# SpladeTable how to fetch a column from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, single-page-application

Started working on a project which will take care of the expiry dates of the articles.

Thought it would be nice to try out splade as a powerful tool for SPA's, as it's only neccessary to keep track of expiry dates (inserting them and listing the dates coming up)

I'm returning a Splade table with values, but since I'm a beginner I have no idea how to implement column from another table in this one.

This is the code for the table:

```php
public function index()
{
    /*
    $items = Item::orderBy('expires_at')->get();
    
    return view('items', compact('items'));
    */
    return view('items', [
        'items' => SpladeTable::for(Item::class)
            ->column('id', 'id', true)
            ->column('barcode', 'Barcode', true)
            ->column('article_name', 'Article Name', true)
            ->column(Expiry::class, 'expires_at', true)
            ->searchInput('article_name', 'Type in article name')
            ->searchInput('barcode', 'Use the scanner')
            ->searchInput('sifra', 'Type in article number')
            ->defaultSort('expires_at')
            ->paginate(20),
    ]);
}
```

I have the column "expires_at" since the second parameter is for that, true is sortable, but have no idea how to fetch actual data.

Also, I updated the expires table so I have values in it related to items but they don't show.

Edit: forgot to mention everything works, checked DBeaver and all is good, table lists everything I want from the items table, just the expires_at column is empty.

Comment: Isn't expires_at a column from the items table? seeing your commented out query, that seems to be the case. If it's not, you'll need to show how it relates to item. Is there a relationship defined with another model? which one? Have you read the documentation available for splade table? What is the query you would do to get the expires_at column normally?

Comment: Hey, no, expires_at is in the Expires table, model Expiry, the commented out section is from before I noticed I need another table for it because one Item can have more Expiry dates. 
The only two models are Expiry and Item classes, Expiry belongsTo Item and Item hasMany Expiry classes.
I read the documentation thoroughly but can't find a thing.
I was thinking maybe getting all from Expiry inside of the ItemController like $expires = Expiry::all(); 
And then calling it in the column somehow?

Comment: Solved :D Guy on discord helped, said to me to use something I used in the very beginning, but had a typo........ Thank you for trying at least :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it didn't work the first time. Then I went onto discord and an user called J87 said to me:

> "Just use regular Laravel relations like
> ->column('relationName.column')"

IT WORKS!